# UI Tab Bar and Navigation Bar to Detail View

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am having a lot of trouble right now getting my navigaton bar to work properly. The following is my hierachy.

```
TabBarController
  -- NavigationController
    -- View
  -- Navigation Controller
    -- View
  -- Navigation Controller
    -- View
```

I have a abstract class that I inherit from for every tab bar view. This abstract class is set as a NavigationBar delegate and has a navigationbar iboutlet.

In one of my views I have setup a table view and when someone selects the table view I want it to go to a more detailed view. The following is the code I am using to do that. When I setup the xib, I dragged a NavigationBar onto the view and then set the ViewController of "VisitedPlace" as the delegate for the navigation bar.

```
//  Called when a row in the table view has been selected.
//  This method will change the view to the current place detailed view
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath {

    NSLog(@"We are here, and proud of it I suppose~");
    PlaceViewController *placeView = [[PlaceViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PlaceView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:placeView animated:YES];
    [placeView release];
    placeView = nil;
```

}

When I select the row the log message is printed, but nothing occurs.

I'm very lost at the moment, I must be missing some crucial. I was reading about a NavigationController and how I have to implement it, but to be completely honest I have no idea how to do that.

EDIT:
When I NSLog'd self.navigationController it was nil so I dragged a NavigatonController and set the Delegate as the File Owner of VisitedPlaces. However, the nav controller is still nil.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: verify that self.navigationController isn't nil

Comment: It is nil. I have dragged a Navigation controller into the VisitedPLaces.xib. I want the nav bar to push and pop views while the tab bar is still in place.

Comment: I actually figured out what I had wrong, I watched a really good tutorial from orielly you can find it here:http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LBnPfAtswgw&feature=player_embedded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hierarchy at the top of your question shows navigation controllers, but then you described dragging navigation bars to your views in interface builder. I think you're confusing those two things. You're adding a navigation bar to your existing view, but the navigation bar is just a UIView subclass. Adding it to your view doesn't create a navigation controller (a UIViewController subclass) as well, so this is why you're getting nil for your self.navigationController property and why nothing happens when you send the push message to that property.

First, you should read up on the MVC (model, view, controller) design pattern if you haven't already, because the distinction between a view and a controller is what you need to understand here.

UINavigationControllers don't directly display much content. All they do is manage a stack of other UIViewControllers. The UINavigationBar is the only view that a UIViewController displays directly. When you tell the navigation controller to push a view controller onto the stack, the navigation controller changes the navigation bar appropriately and animates the new view controller's view onscreen. The UINavigationBar is just a dumb UIView that gets managed by the navigation controller. It doesn't itself contain any of the functionality for managing the view controller stack (which should be an obvious assumption for the MVC approach, hence my suggestion above).

Somewhere, either in interface builder or your code (I prefer the latter), you need to create a UINavigationController. Actually, you need to create one for each of the tabs in your tab bar. Set your UITabBarController's `viewControllers` property to an array of these navigationcontrollers.

Then, each of those navigation controllers needs to be given a view controller to display as their first item. You do this by setting the `rootViewController` property of the navigation controller to the view controller that you want to display at the top of the navigation controller's stack.

Do you follow this? I don't feel like I'm doing a very good job explaining it. I hope this helps. If not, say so and I'll try to do better.

**edit**

Just FYI, there are times when you might want to use a UINavigationBar without the navigation controller. That would be if you're implementing your own system for keeping track of the view controllers and animating them on and off screen. Same goes for UITabBar, another view that shouldn't be confused with the view controller with a similar name.

Answer (score 0):

Debug and check whether the `self` pointing to visitedPlaced object or not